# I have installed react-native-bootsplash, the splashscreen is not showing my logo else shows like a inner rouded image like the below:

Tags: reactjs, react-native, splash-screen

[This is the image after bundling completes :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpi76.jpg)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/BootTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BootTheme" parent="Theme.BootSplash">
    <item name="bootSplashBackground">@color/bootsplash_background</item>
    <item name="bootSplashLogo">@drawable/bootsplash_logo</item>
    <item name="postBootSplashTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.app;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;
import com.zoontek.rnbootsplash.RNBootSplash;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
   
  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "app";
  }


 

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. Here we use a util class {@link
   * DefaultReactActivityDelegate} which allows you to easily enable Fabric and Concurrent React
   * (aka React 18) with two boolean flags.
   */
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled());
  }

   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RNBootSplash.init(this, R.style.BootTheme); // ⬅️ initialize the splash screen
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // or super.onCreate(null) with react-native-screens
  }
}
```

I want my logo to be present on the splashscreen rather than a insetted image like i have given above , any help would be appreciated . As , this is the only issue for me , so Kindly , share this issue to your friends or if possible provide me a solution by any chance.

Comment: I'm currently having this same issue. the above image shows up only on android immediately after the splash screen

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash/issues/456, seems to be an inherent problem